# git diff between remote and local (ignoring non-pushed commits)

Tags: git

I'm looking to see the best way to see changes on a given remote branch after a `git fetch`, but I want to ignore the changes I've committed (but not pushed/merged).  Generally, my flow is

```
 git commit
 git commit # something else
 git fetch
 git diff HEAD^^..origin/stable # HEAD^^ is the commit right before my two commits above
```

Wanted to see if there was a way to handle that HEAD^^ to show me what has changed between what I knew of origin/stable (in this case, HEAD^^) and what origin/stable is after the fetch.

Basically, I want to see all new code committed to the branch since my last fetch, ignoring any staged (or unstaged) changes I have on my local branch.

Thanks for the help.

### Solution

Based on @carl-norum's answer below, I added the following to .git/config

```
 [alias]
    fetch-diff = !git fetch 2>&1 | awk '/[a-z0-9]+[.][.][a-z0-9]+/ { print $1 }' | xargs -L 1 git diff
```

and now use `git fetch-diff` which will fetch and print the diffs for each branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git diff HEAD^^ origin/stable
```

Should do exactly what you're looking for.  However, the `fetch` operation should provide you some output like:

```
76e5999..0564fab  master     -> origin/master
```

Showing what hashes changed on `origin/master` (in my example).  You could just do:

```
git diff 76e5999 0564fab
```

And see all of those diffs.

Comment: Thanks for your help here.  Two questions: is there a good way to do this through an alias?  As in `git fetch-diff`, etc?  Or, better, is there a way to pull that information that came from fetch after the fact?

Comment: I added my solution which is exactly what I wanted based on your answer.  Can you give it a lookover and if you agree, add it to your comment so I can accept.  Thanks!